# Linux transpose long format to wide format

Tags: python, linux, awk, transpose

Im looking to transpose a file from long format using either an awk statement or Python.

My input file would look like this;

```
ID Chr_Position Geno
111 1_1234 0
111 1_12345 1
111 1_2345 0
111 2_23245 2
```

and my required output would like to be (header not necessarily needed)

```
ID 1_1234 1_12345 2_2345
111 0 1 0 2
112 1 1 1 1
113 1 1 0 2
```

They are big files, over 100,000 IDs with over 10,000 rows each but can split into smaller if needed.
I have previous code that will transpose rows and columns but not sure how to take it from long format.

Comment: Why are `1_2345` and `2_23245` absent from your header line? Where did `2_2345` appear from? Where did the `112` and `113` lines appear from in your output (if the answer is from your input file then edit your sample input file to include them)?

Answer (score 1):

idk how to generate the output you posted given the input file you posted but maybe this'll help get you on the track:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==1 { next }
$1 != prev { if (line!="") print prev line; line=""; prev=$1 }
{ line = line OFS $NF }
END { if (line!="") print prev line }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
111 0 1 0 2
```

Answer (score 1):

if your data is well structured (the same number of columns/rows in the same order, consistent separators) you can try this

```
$ sed 1d file | pr -4ats' ' | cut -d' ' -f1,3,6,9,12

111 0 1 0 2
112 1 0 4 3
```

for the test data file

```
$ cat file

ID Chr_Position Geno
111 c1 0
111 c2 1
111 c3 0
111 c4 2
112 c1 1
112 c2 0
112 c3 4
112 c4 3
```